# How do I stop useEffect from running when rendering a modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react movie app. I'm still working on my hero picture which shows a popular movie/show in random but whenever I click the button to open a modal, useEffect runs then changes the movie in the hero slide. How do I stop useEffect from running after rendering a modal then run when that modal is closed?:

````
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  //Select movie in random so main page displays a different popular movie everytime the page loads
  const randomPopularMovie = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(requests.requestPopular).then((response) => {
      setMovies(response.data.results);
    });
  }, []);```
````

Answer (score 0):

because it gets reassigned on every rerender. You can put it in a state, memo or ref

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  //Select movie in random so main page displays a different popular movie everytime the page loads
  const [randomPopularMovie,setRandomPopularMovie] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(requests.requestPopular).then((response) => {
      setMovies(response.data.results)
      setRandomPopularMovie(response.data.results[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)])
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
let mounted = false;

(async () => {
 const {data} = await axios.get(requests.requestPopular) 
 
 if(response.status === 'success' && mounted) {
             setMovies(data.results);
                }

}())


return () => {mounted = false}
}, [])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).